# How to generate autocomplete-ready query hooks with custom injectGetItems function in Redux Toolkit Query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have created a custom `injectGetItems` function to avoid code repetition and make it generic. This function is used to generate query endpoints and return autocomplete-ready query hooks. The goal is to eliminate the need for manually creating repetitive code blocks like `enhancedApi.injectEndpoints` for each API call.

Here's an example usage of the `injectGetItems` function:

```js
export const { useGetCharacterQuery } = injectGetItems<CharacterResponse, void>(
  'getCharacter', 
  TAG_TYPES.rickAndMorty,
  QUERY_URL.rickandmorty_character
);
```

In the above code, I expect the `useGetCharacterQuery` query hook to be recognized and auto-completed by my IDE. However, the IDE currently shows it as `any` instead of inferring the correct type.

The `injectGetItems` function internally performs the following operations:

```js
import { baseApi } from '../api';

export const injectGetItems = <ApiResponse, ApiArgs>(
  name: string,
  tag: string,
  url: string,
): any {
  const enhancedApi = baseApi.enhanceEndpoints({ addTagTypes: [tag] });

  const entityApi = enhancedApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      [name]: builder.query<ApiResponse, ApiArgs>({
        query: () => url,
        providesTags: (result) =>
          Array.isArray(result)
            ? [
              ...result.map((item) => ({
                type: tag,
                id: item.id,
              })),
              { type: tag, id: 'LIST' },
            ]
            : [{ type: tag, id: 'LIST' }],
      }),
    }),
  });
    
  return entityApi;
};
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to modify the `injectGetItems` function or provide the necessary typings to ensure the generated query hooks are correctly inferred and auto-completed by the IDE.

**I have tried the following:**

```js
import { baseApi } from './baseApi';

type ReturnGetName<T extends string> = {
  [K in `use${Capitalize<T>}Query`]: baseApi['endpoints'][T]['useQuery'];
};

export const injectGetItems = <ApiResponse, ApiArgs>(
  name: string,
  tag: string,
  url: string,
): ReturnGetName<typeof name> => {
  const enhancedApi = baseApi.enhanceEndpoints({ addTagTypes: [tag] });

  enhancedApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      [name]: builder.query<ApiResponse, ApiArgs>({
        queryFn: () => url,
        providesTags: (result) =>
          Array.isArray(result)
            ? [
                ...result.map((item) => ({
                  type: tag,
                  id: item.id,
                })),
                { type: tag, id: 'LIST' },
              ]
            : [{ type: tag, id: 'LIST' }],
      }),
    }),
  });

  const returnObj: ReturnGetName<typeof name> = {
    [`use${capitalize(name)}Query`]: enhancedApi.endpoints[name].useQuery,
  };

  return returnObj;
};
```